# Como faço um nome que foram criados contar 1

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

**Estou tentando adicionar os nomes contar um numero que foram criados, abaixo do nome de titulo esta numero 3 certo ? , eu sei que numero 3 é porque eu peguei numero da letra.
Mas como faço isso ?**

---

- Exemplo 1 - sim   2 - sim

---

[image]

```js
let a = []

function botao() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome")
  var r = document.getElementById("res")
  if (nome.value == "") {
    alert("Por favor digite um nome!")
  }
  if (nome.value.length) {
    a.push(nome)
    r.innerHTML += ` <tr><th scope="row">${nome.value.length}</th> <td>${nome.value}</td>`
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center mt-3">
    Agenda
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nome</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="res">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
  <h1 class="text-center mt-2 mb-4">Registe por aqui</h1>
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="NOME">
  <input type="submit" id="btn" onclick="botao()">
</div>
```

Comment: olha li 2x e não consegui entender o que quer fazer

Comment: Tranquilo, você viu na imagem abaixo do nome tem um numero (3) certo?
quero fazer tipo  primeira que foi criado chamado (1- ricardo) segunda vez  (2 - julio) entendeu?

mas na imagem que esta (3 - sim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você está mudando o tamanho do array, cada vez que coloca um item, você pode trocar o tamanho da palavra

```
r.innerHTML += ` <tr><th scope="row">${nome.value.length}</th> <td>${nome.value}</td>`
```

pelo tamanho do array:

```
r.innerHTML += ` <tr><th scope="row">${a.length}</th> <td>${nome.value}</td>`
```

Comment: É isso mesmo, Obrigado fera!